# Is it possible to make custom Culture / Region combinations?

Tags: c#, .net, localization

I would like to support something like a `NL-Us` culture. Is this possible?

Comment: @Sven - It means you need to learn a bit more about cultures in .NET ;)

Comment: @Oded: While you can make custom cultures, I'm questioning what an nl-US culture would mean. nl-NL is Dutch regional settings, as applicable in the Netherlands, and nl-BE is Dutch, as applicable in Belgium. So nl-US would be Dutch, as applicable in the US? But the US *doesn't* use Dutch anywhere, so it doesn't mean anything.

Comment: The only question is what you need it for. Certainly, you don't need any custom culture combined from two existing ones. Everything you need like formatting, displaying localized resources could be done without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [it is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469.aspx).

You need to start with [`CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureandregioninfobuilder.aspx) - the link above is a full howto on MSDN.

Comment: Hi @Oded, Is "CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder" still available in 4.5 and 4.6 ?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @bunjeeb - you linked to documentation that suggests that yes, it is.

Answer (score 2):

A quick search found fellow MVP Paulo Morgado, who has created a tool for setting up custom culture and region information:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/CultureAndRegionInfoTool.aspx

Not sure if fits your need, but the question WAS rather open ended. Hope this helps.